# Why async/await doesn't synchronizes ioredis get method execution inside a forEach loop?

Tags: node.js, async-await, ioredis

Async/Await approach:

```
Ids = ['abc','lmn','xyz']

Ids.forEach(function (resId){
    console.log('inside loop');
    async function operation(){
        var curObj = await redisClient.get('key1');
        console.log('done waiting');
  }
}
```

Callback approach on another function:

```
function operation(cb) {
         redisClient.get('key1', cb);
       }
operation(function(){
    console.log('inside operation');
});
```

I wanted wait till the curObj variable sets and execute the code sequentially to print the 'done waiting'. I used async/await but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Then I used callback with the same get method still the same. I use ioredis library.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Async/await approuch should look like this:

```
(async() => {
  const Ids = ['abc','lmn','xyz'];

  const operation = async (){
   var curObj = await redisClient.get('key1');
   console.log('done waiting');
  }


  for (const resId of Ids){
   console.log('inside loop');
   await operation();
  }
})()
```

There is no `async` in `forEach` loop, but you can use it with `for...of`. 
Note, I'm using IIFE function just for example how to use async/await without other context.